# How to get @html.HiddenFor Model value to Razor Variable?

Tags: variables, razor, model

Hope u all are Fine ...!
I want to add a link in my grid for delete the whole row from database the controller is working but how can I get the value of @html.HiddenFor in ActionLink as my Loop Code in View is as Following :

```
 @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE)
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].SLAB_SEQUENCE)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_LOW)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_HIGH)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_RATE)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_MIN_VALUE)</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_MAX_VALUE)</td>
                <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id =  "56"}) </td>

            </tr>
        }
```

in this code I want the 'TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE' value instead of "56" soo Please Elaborate this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're iterating over `Model`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
```

So presumably the value you want in any given iteration of the loop is this?:

```
Model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE
```

Just use that value where you want to use it:

```
Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE })
```

Aside from that, it's not entirely clear what the hidden input is needed for in the first place.  Presumably you have one big form in which this table resides?  This shouldn't affect that though.  The action link is just a normal link, all you're doing here is putting a value in the URL of that link.

---

Side note: An `<input>` directly within a `<tr>` is invalid.  Put the hidden input inside one of the cells:

```
<td>
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE)
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = Model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE })
</td>
```

Comment: You might be right but in my case it didn't work so I write my own code and it is :              <td>@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = @Html.ValueFor(model => model[i].TAX_SLAB_SEQUENCE) })</td>

Comment: hey @David can u please help me as I'm facing a new Problem also I'm new can't understand everything clearly so

Comment: @HussnainSajid: A "new problem" likely involves posting a new question on Stack Overflow.  Previous questions are not to be mistaken for ongoing tutoring services.